# Pointers to chars in C

Tags: c, pointers

The question is: what is the difference between

```
char c = 'a';
char *p = &c;
```

AND

```
char c = 'a';
char *p;
*p = &c;
```

The result of execution is very different (the first as expected and the second is compilation error). I have just started "Pointers", so please, be patient about it.

Comment: For them to be the same, the third line needs to be `p = &c;` Compiler warnings are useful in a case like this: "`char` differs in levels of indirection from `char *`"

Comment: `*p = &c` is a type mismatch.  Also, since `p` is not initialized, attempting to access `*p` is undefined behavior.  `p` stores an address, and  since `p` is not initialized, its value is not a valid address.

Comment: Be careful with `char *p = &c;`, because this will not be a null-terminated string. Most functions accepting `char*` expect a null-terminated string and will result in undefined behavior if that's not what they get.

Comment: Think of `char *p` as `char* p`.  The type of p is `char *`.  Then it's obvious that the next line should be `p = &c`.  But don't write it this way, which will mess you up when you try to put multiple pointers in one line: `char *p, *q;`

Comment: This has to be a duplicate. Can somebody find some originals?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Difference between different ways of initializing pointers in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790021/difference-between-different-ways-of-initializing-pointers-in-c)

Comment: If you don't see an error message for `*p = &c;` then fix your compiler settings

Comment: I would like to ask people who prefer `char *p` over `char* p` to chime in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, it helps if you consider that in C a declaration is a `type` followed by a list of `names`.

In the line

```
    char c = 'a';
```

`c` is the name and `char` is the type.

And when you declare

```
    char        *p = &c;
```

it is a bit strange and leads to confusion. The asterisk has different meanings in C depending on this position:

- it is the operator for *multiplication*.
- it is also the *dereference* operator, one that is also called the *indirection* operator, as if it was not sufficiently confusing.
- in a declaration it indicates a pointer.

We can not blame C, since the language was designed for systems programming and not for teaching, as Pascal was designed for, years later.

Back to the issue, in the line

```
    char        *p = &c;
```

`p` is the name, and the type is `char*` as the compiler sometimes tells you in error messages.

So in fact the compiler sees

```
    char*            p = &c;
```

And `p` is a pointer to a `char`.

But what do you see in `*p`?  `*p` means the content of whatever `p` points to.

```
    Spaceship* p = &some_ship; // *p is Spaceship
    int* p = NULL;             // *p is an int
    char**** p = some_stuff;   // *p is char***
```

In that sense, as you are learning about pointers, keep in mind the relation between the operator `&` *address-of operator*, and the operator `*` *indirection operator*, as they signal inverse operations. And keep the `*` near the type in the declaration.

if `pc` is `char****` then

- `*pc` is `char***`
- `**pc` is `char**`
- `***pc` is `char*`
- `****pc` is a single `char` as stated in the declaration.
- `&pc` is the address of a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer of a `char`.

By writing `char  *p` instead of `char*  p` this C idiosyncrasy is exposed: if `p` is `char*` then `*p` is a `char`. And you can read it wrong if you keep the asterisk far from the type and next to the name...

#### See this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char    c = 'a';
    char*   p = &c;
    printf("c is '%c' at %p, sizeof(c) is %lu\n", c, &c, sizeof(c) );
    printf("p is char* at %p, sizeof(p) is %lu\n", p, sizeof(p) );
    printf("and in that address we have *p = '%c'\n", *p );
    return 0;
}
```

that shows

```
so>  gcc -o tst -Wall f30.c
so>  ./tst
c is 'a' at 0x7fffdfa36d3f, sizeof(c) is 1
p is char* at 0x7fffdfa36d3f, sizeof(p) is 8
and in that address we have *p = 'a'
so>
```

Comment: This "explanation" with all the whitespace might work for this very simple case, but it doesn't work for other declarations like `int a(int);` or `int (*b)[5];`

Comment: This is an "explanation" precisely for the very simple case. As noted by the author, he is starting with "Pointers" :)

Comment: when starting to learn something one may be grateful for "all the whitespace" and the so many words.

Answer (score 3):

The * has different meanings when declaring a variable verses assigning an existing variable.

When declaring the variable * means that the variable p is a pointer to a char instead of just a char.

On the other hand in the assignment to an existing variable the * dereferences a pointer. That is rather than working on the pointer the asaignment would work on the location pointed to by the pointer,

So your second example is doubly broken

Firstly it dereferences an uninitialized pointer. Secondly when it tries to make the assignment  it has a type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of code is correct but the second one is not because you tried to assign a value to variable with a different type.

In other words `*p` and `&c` are two different types of variables. In order to correct it, you need to write:

```
p = &c;
```

Answer (score 1):

The

```
char *p = &c;
```

is initialization of the pointer p with address of variable c, while

```
*p = &c;
```

is assignment where the pointer p is dedeferenced and the address of c is written to the address in memory which p is specifying. For your code depending on the context this could be the address 0 (if p is a zero pointer) or some random address in most cases (since p is not initialized).

Answer (score 1):

C lets you initialize, i.e. declare and assign at the same time. With pointers, it matters whether the `*` is included or not:

```
char *p = &c;
^^^^^^^     
   |  ^^^^^^
   |     |
 decl.   |
        ass.
```

Only `p` overlaps. What is being assigned to is `p`, not `*p`. On two lines:

```
char *p;
p = &c
```

`p` is an address/pointer. But with just `*p` (or `p[0]` or p[...]) it is turned into a char. These two sides of a pointer almost overlap in a initialization like above.

Answer (score -1):

The first is parsed as

```
(char *) p = & c;
```

i.e., "a variable p, of type char *, is initialized with the address of c".

the latter

```
*p = &c;
```

is parsed as "take the variable p, *dereference what it points to*, and assign that the address of c". That fails, because what p points to is a char, not a char*.

Comment: The syntax for a declaration is a type name followed by declarator list,  so your statement is incorrect; it's parsed as type name `char` with declarator `*p` and then initializer.   C declarations use infix syntax, not prefix as you suggest, the two cases only look the same for extremely simple declarations.  Consider `char q[5];` vs `char[5] q;`